# Finding the function of a sine graph that has both translation and transformation

Tags: functions, trigonometry, transformation

I can't quite find a problem similar enough to this yet, and I need some serious help.
Here is a photo of the graph of the function I am trying to find out:

[image]

Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to post a physical copy of the photo yet. I've figured out most of the problem. The basic formula for a sine graph is $\sin(2\pi/P(x−b))$. So far from the picture, I've figured out that the amplitude is $4$ and the frequency (is that right?) is $2\pi/5$ and that $x$ will most definitely be negative. My problem is in finding b, which for the life of me I can't figure out. So far I've hit $4\sin(2\pi/5(-x-1.5))$, but that doesn't seem to be correct. Can you guys explain what I'm doing wrong, so that I can learn how to do this correctly?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplitude and wavelegth(time-period) are ok. You have to recognise two things in addition. The y- shift up and the associated phase angle for x- shift. Try
$$ y= 3+ 4 \cos \frac {2 \pi ( x+2)}{ 5} $$

Comment: This answer is not correct. The format I was given to find the function is asin(2π/P(x−b))+c so I'm pretty sure b will be negative.

Comment: Note that $ \cos .. = \sin ( \pi/2 - ..)$, so write this in terms of sine.

Comment: Ha--this is a much better solution than mine (I feel like I cheated in a way). I'm going to bed. +1

Comment: Fine, thanks, appreciate..

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It worked!!! It's too bad I was going about this the wrong way, looking at sine versus cosine. You are awesome! :D

Comment: $\cos$ is a natural choice because @ x=-2, 3 and 4 add upto 7 seen right up in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was unfortunate--the phase shift, as you noted, is the real challenge here (I'll chalk up my careless previous answer to this being way past my bedtime). Try graphing the following: $4\sin\left[\dfrac{2\pi}{5}\left(x-1-\dfrac{5\sin^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})}{2\pi}\right)\right]+3$:

[image]

Given the construction of the function, I imagine you will be able to tell what is going on. If not, feel free to comment.

Comment: you're right about the phase shift being the important part. This is still marked as incorrect (basically there is an online system checking to see if the problem is marked as correct or not; like you I'm tired and totally burned out. I've worked on this problem for over 4 hours.) My real concern is how would I go about finding the shift given only the information of the graph.

Comment: The other answer is the way to go. Make the adjustment, as indicated and it should be "marked as correct." The key identity, and the one I should have used as well, is that $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$.